# Folder sizes at 0 bytes with Samba shares on Windows 7

Tags: linux, windows, samba, server-message-block, shares

Background info:

- Running Samba version 3.6.9
- Successfully authenticating shares with Active Directory (user/file permissions)
- Able to successfully connect to shares - no issues at all.

So, basically, Samba is working like a champ. One issue that we're seeing on Windows 7 systems is that folder sizes show as 0 bytes when you look at the properties when using Windows 7. Files show their sizes, but folders do not. I found this posting already, https://serverfault.com/questions/580830/samba-folder-properties-incorrectly-shows-0-bytes-and-0-files-in-windows-7, but it does not address the same issue we are experiencing. To add, on a Windows 2003 system we can see folder sizes so it appears to be related to Windows 7.

Curious if anyone else has encountered this and found a fix? Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

** FOUND RESOLUTION **

I fixed the issue but forgot to come back here and update what I did. In smb.conf I set the following parameters:

```
server signing = auto
client signing = auto
```

That fixed the issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the issue but forgot to come back here and update what I did. In smb.conf I set the following parameters:

```
server signing = auto
client signing = auto
```

That fixed the issue!

Comment: Can you tell us as well why this is solving the problem?

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I believe it has to do with how Windows 7 implements the SMB protocol. When set to auto, Samba and Windows negotiate. https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html